# how to extract unknown names out of a string

Tags: java, string, extract

I'm trying to make a Minecraft Server control panel, and I want to get a list of all online players, each username in it's own String. The way you get the users is typing /list and it returns a string. the returned string looks like:

[HH:MM:SS] INFO: username1, username2, username3, and username4

so, how would i extract each username into it's own string? I've googled this, and looked as similar questions, and I cant find a useful answer. I thought about string.replaceAll(); but i cant seem to get that to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: yes, but again, how would i implement that into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

`String.split(", ");`

This will split the string to an array.

Here is how> [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)

```
String usernames = ...; // fill with data
```

`String[] data = usernames.split(", ");`

Afther this you must remove the date and time from the first name.

Comment: So, for example, lets say that the string in my question is `s`. I would take s.split(","); and to get to the list of usernames, they would start at s[2]?

Comment: alright cool. i'll try this when i get home from school, so if it works you'll get the +1 and answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer with a few more technical details:

```
String[] usernames = String.split(",");
```

**In order to extract the first username, you'll have to do something like:**

```
String username1 = usernames[0].split("INFO:")[1]; // not sure if you need ":" or "\:", so check it out...
```

This is because `usernames[0] == "[HH:MM:SS] INFO: username1"`, and you want to split it into the sub-string that appears before "INFO:" and the sub-string that appears after it.

**In order to extract the remaining usernames, just iterate the `usernames` array from index 1.**

For example:

```
for (int i=1; i<usernames.length; i++)
    System.out.println(usernames[i]);
```

Note: you might want to strip off leading and/or trailing spaces, using `strip()`.

Comment: what is the `[1]` on the split for?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what lucian said:

```
String [] data = s.split(", ");
data[0]=data[0].replaceAll("[HH:MM:SS] INFO: ", "");
```

Should replace the unwanted beginning of that string with nothing ("");

Comment: except that the `[HH:MM:SS]` isnt actually that, it is an actual time... would that still work?

Comment: Oh then you need `data[0]=data[0].replaceAll("\[([0-9]){2}\:([0-9]){2}\:([0-9]){2}\] INFO\: ", "");` try that.